# Object instance vs Closure

Tags: javascript

What the is the difference of an Object instance and a Closure?

When should I use the other? And are there any differences?

Im considering this:

```
// closure (?)
function multiplier(factor) {
    return function(number) {
        return factor * number;
    };
}

// I shouldnt use "new" here right?
var twice = multiplier(2);
console.log(twice(2)); // --> 4

var tripple = multiplier(3);
console.log(tripple(2)); // --> 6



// object instance (?)
function multiplier2(factor) {

    this.do = function(number) {
        return factor * number;
    };
}

var twice2 = new multiplier2(2);
console.log(twice2.do(2)); // --> 4

var tripple2 = new multiplier2(3);
console.log(tripple2.do(2)); // --> 6
```

Comment: These are 2 different things.  The first is a function that when called returns you a function (a closure).  The 2nd is creating a new object  That object can have properties/methods.  These 2 things serve different purposes.

Comment: @RocketHazmat yes I understand that they are different things. But, with my current knowledge, I cant see the difference.. Couldnt I add properties/methods to the closure (if I return an object instead) and then get the same result as with the new object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Technically, in JavaScript all functions are closures.  (Semantically you could argue they only are if they reference variables outside of their local scope.)

The only difference in this case is whether the function is a *constructor function*.  When you say `new multiplier(2)` you are instructing the language to call the `multiplier` function with a single argument, but to call it with `this` (the context variable) set to a new object with a prototype that refers back to `multiplier`.

In both cases you have a function, and there isn't any real difference between the two in terms of how JavaScript sees them.  You can call a constructor function without `new` (but you **shouldn't ever**, because `this` will refer to something else, which you will clobber).

I tend to follow Douglas Crockford's advice on the topic, and I never use `new`.  It's less error-prone to write *power constructors* -- functions that create objects themselves and return them, instead of expecting the language to create the object prior to the function call:

```
function multiplier2(factor) {
    var that = {};

    that.do = function(number) {
        return factor * number;
    };

    return that;
}

var twice2 = multiplier2(2);
console.log(twice2.do(2)); // --> 4
```

Comment: Some questions:  

1. What do you mean with "but to call it with this (the context variable) set to a new object with a prototype that refers back to multiplier."?  

2. First you say that I never should call a constructor func without `new`, but in the next paragraf you say you bever use `new`.. I'm confused! :)

Tnx for the reply!

Comment: hmm, I think I understand my second question now. My method is a constructor function, but you return an object instead (which is kinda the same?).  

But if I use your(Crockfords) advice, then I cant use prototype, right?

Comment: One LAST question. Why do I need the `that` variable? if I change it to this, it still works?

Comment: You can still use prototypes, but you would create objects using [`Object.create()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create) instead of just `{}`.  No, you can't use `this` as a variable name, because it is a reserved word.